# First Data Gateway Question

Tags: windows-server-2008, firstdata

We are currently running Linkpoint gateway on a server 2000.  We are trying to make the transition to a server 2008 x64.

We have these files so far.
LpiCom_6_0.dll
LinkPointTransaction.dll
Interop.LPICOM_6_OLib.dll

We have installed OpenSSL.

Can anyone help us with a step by step procedure on what to do?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

===================================================================

Needed DLL's for linkpoint:

```
LinkPointTransaction.dll 
Interop.LPICOM_6_0Lib.dll 
LpiCom_6_0.dll
```

===================================================================

## STEPS TO FOLLOW

Step 1 - IIS 7.0> Application Pools > set Application Pool Default > Enable 32 Bit to TRUE

Step 2 - Install OPENSSL

Step 3 - Remove lpssl.dll from the server, if necessary.

Step 4 - Register LpiCom_6_0.dll (regsvr32)

```
CMD as administrator

c:\windows\syswow64
regsvr c:\windows\syswow64\LpiCom_6_0.dll
```

Step 6 - Put LinkPointTransaction.dll and Interop.LPICOM_6_0Lib.dll in the open ssl bin folder of application.

Comment: Chirs, I need these DLLs I am havinf problem with Linkpoint Gateway as I moved my app to 64 Bit Server Windows 2008 R2. I tried all possible ways to find these Dlls. Can you please share those if you have?

Answer (score 1):

I emailed First Data about this in researching upgrading our servers. This was their repsonse:

> Thank you for your recent inquiry regarding First Data Global Gateway. The Webservice API is our current solution for 64 bit machines running on IIS 7 as none of the dll files (Linkpointtransaction.dll, LPICOM_6_.dll) will be updated to work with the 64bit server.  Webservice API will require to install the client certificate and send the transaction via SOAP request. Additional information on Webservice API is found at http://www.firstdata.com/downloads/marketing-merchant/FDGG-Web-Service-API-v4.0.pdf.
>
> If you need further clarifications or questions, please contact our support desk via phone number below. Please be advised the API support desk hours is from 9:00AM to 6:00PM EST Mon-Fri.

This should help others looking for similar information in the future.

Answer (score 0):

I found that I had to add lpssl.dll to the path.  To do this you have one of two options:

1. Copy lpssl.dll to a folder that is already in the path.  You can see what folders are in the path by typing 'echo %PATH%' at a command prompt.

OR

1. Add the folder that lpssl.dll is in to the path.  To do this, right-click on My Computer, then Properties, then Advanced System Settings, then on the Advanced tab click 'Environment Variables', then in the lower box with 'System Variables' find the 'Path' variable and double-click it.  If your lpssl.dll is at c:\myprojects\coolwebsite\bin\lpssl.dll, then you want to append this to the end of the current path string (starting with adding a semicolon to separate it from the previous paths:   ;c:\myprojects\coolwebsite\bin

I've written more about my troubles with the LinkPoint pieces on my blog at http://adventuresindotnet.blogspot.com/2012/02/linkpointtransactiondll.html

There are probably other steps you have to take, but hopefully this will help somewhat.